# Bad: flutter Math Confusion

Tags: dart

I create a widget that contains a Drawer but I can't use it, I get this error.

[i get this error in use the drawer widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqiFJ.png)

[The code of drawer widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqTmk.png)

Comment: I can use the drawer in any page..but need use all code..but i need create a individual widget and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error you provide us has noting to do with drawer widget, this error is produced from Image Widget, so I do recommend checking your Image.network() widget, I think the path you provide is not acceptable, maybe you should use Image.asset()

Comment: failed again...

Comment: just try replace image.netwrok with a container for example, i think every thing should work fine

Comment: Yes, the error is fixed! Ty